# Show lines with a point for ChartJS legend labels

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to create a ChartJS legend which displays a line with a point in its centre for each label, so that you can identify a dataset in the legend by a certain styled line and type of point.

So far, I have been able to either use individual points in a dataset for the legend labels, or display a styled line without an extra point by using a custom `generateLabels` function.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gpkdvjb5/33/

The version of ChartJS I'm using is v3.9.1.

```js
const NUM_DATA = 7;
const NUM_CFG = {count: NUM_DATA, min: 0, max: 100};
const data = {
  labels: ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Dataset: 1',
      data: [100, 150, 150, 100, 150, 150, 100],
      pointRadius: 10,
      pointStyle: 'rect',
      borderDash: [5,18],
      borderColor: 'blue',
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      fill: false,
    },
    {
      label: 'Dataset: 1',
      data: [200, 170, 170, 200, 170, 170, 200],
      borderDash: [5,5,5],
      pointRadius: 10,
      borderColor: 'blue',
      pointStyle: 'crossRot',
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
      fill: false,
    },
  ],
};

const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        labels: {
            usePointStyle: true
        }
      }
    }
  },
};

config.options.plugins.legend.labels.pointStyleWidth = 60;
        
// Using line styling for labels instead of points
config.options.plugins.legend.labels.generateLabels = (chart) => {
    const datasets = chart.data.datasets;
    const options = chart.options.legend || {};
    return chart._getSortedDatasetMetas().map((meta) => {
        const style = meta.controller.getStyle();

        return {
            text: datasets[meta.index].label,
            fillStyle: style.backgroundColor,
            hidden: !meta.visible,
            lineCap: style.borderCapStyle,
            lineDash: style.borderDash,
            lineDashOffset: style.borderDashOffset,
            lineJoin: style.borderJoinStyle,
            lineWidth: style.borderWidth,
            strokeStyle: style.borderColor,
            pointStyle: 'line',
            rotation: style.rotation,
            // Below is extra data used for toggling the datasets
            datasetIndex: meta.index
        };
    });
};

let canvas = document.getElementById('test-canvas');
let chart = new Chart(
    canvas,
    config
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="test-canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your custom legend label using the `HTMLCanvasElement` option for the `pointStyle` of the label returned by the `generateLabels` function.

A simplified application of that technique for your code would be:

```js
const NUM_DATA = 7;
const NUM_CFG = {count: NUM_DATA, min: 0, max: 100};
const data = {
    labels: ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Dataset: red',
            data: [100, 150, 150, 100, 150, 150, 100],
            pointRadius: 10,
            pointStyle: 'rect',
            borderDash: [5,18],
            borderColor: 'blue',
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            fill: false,
        },
        {
            label: 'Dataset: blue',
            data: [200, 170, 170, 200, 170, 170, 200],
            borderDash: [5,5,5],
            pointRadius: 10,
            borderColor: 'blue',
            pointStyle: 'crossRot',
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
            fill: false,
        },
    ],
};

const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                labels: {
                    usePointStyle: true
                }
            }
        }
    },
};

config.options.plugins.legend.labels.pointStyleWidth = 60;

// Using line styling for labels instead of points
config.options.plugins.legend.labels.generateLabels = (chart) => {
    const datasets = chart.data.datasets;
    const options = chart.options.legend || {};
    return chart._getSortedDatasetMetas().map((meta) => {
        const style = meta.controller.getStyle(),
            dataSet = datasets[meta.index];
        return {
            text: dataSet.label,
            hidden: !meta.visible,
            pointStyle: (function(){
                const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                canvas.setAttribute('width', "50");
                canvas.setAttribute('height', "20");
                const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

                context.lineWidth = style.borderWidth;
                context.lineCap = style.borderCapStyle;
                context.lineJoin = style.borderJoinStyle;
                context.setLineDash(style.borderDash);
                context.dashOffset = style.lineDashOffset;
                context.strokeStyle = style.borderColor;

                // draw the line
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(1, 10);
                context.lineTo(50, 10);
                context.stroke();
                context.fillStyle = style.backgroundColor;

                context.setLineDash([]);
                context.lineWidth = 1;
                // draw the standard symbol
                Chart.helpers.drawPoint(context, {
                    pointStyle: dataSet.pointStyle,
                    borderWidth: style.borderWidth,
                    radius: Math.min(dataSet.pointRadius, 10),
                }, 25, 10);

                // or draw a circle
                // context.beginPath();
                // //context.beginPath();
                // context.arc(25, 10, 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                // context.fill();

                return canvas;
            })(),
            //rotation: style.rotation, rotation ignored

            datasetIndex: meta.index
        };
    });
};

let canvas = document.getElementById('test-canvas');
let chart = new Chart(
    canvas,
    config
);
```

```html
<canvas id="test-canvas"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-ElRFoEQdI5Ht6kZvyzXhYG9NqjtkmlkfYk0wr6wHxU9JEHakS7UJZNeml5ALk+8IKlU6jDgMabC3vkumRokgJA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Kikon's answer I tweaked it a little bit for React Typescript version

```js
const chartData: ChartData<"line"> = {
  // 12 months in short month format
  labels: [
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    "Apr",
    "May",
    "Jun",
    "Jul",
    "Aug",
    "Sep",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec",
  ],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Car",
      data: [23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45],
      borderColor: "rgb(53, 162, 235)",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(53, 162, 235, 0.5)",
    },
    {
      label: "Bus",
      data: [15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37],
      borderColor: "rgb(252, 164, 48)",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(252, 164, 48, 0.5)",
    },
    {
      label: "Car (projected)",
      data: [20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42],
      borderColor: "rgb(53, 162, 235)",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(53, 162, 235, 0.5)",
      borderDash: [10, 5],
    },
  ],
};

const options: ChartOptions<"line"> = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      position: "left",
      display: true,
      labels: {
        usePointStyle: true,
        pointStyle: "line",
        pointStyleWidth: 60,
        generateLabels: (chart) => {
          const datasets = chart.data.datasets;
          return chart.getSortedVisibleDatasetMetas().map((meta) => {
            const style = (meta.controller as any).getStyle();
            const dataset = datasets[meta.index];
            return {
              text: dataset.label,
              hidden: !meta.visible,
              pointStyle: (() => {
                const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.setAttribute("width", "50");
                canvas.setAttribute("height", "20");
                const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                if (!context) return canvas;
                context.lineWidth = style.borderWidth;
                context.lineCap = style.borderCapStyle;
                context.lineJoin = style.borderJoinStyle;
                context.setLineDash(style.borderDash);
                context.lineDashOffset = style.lineDashOffset;
                context.strokeStyle = style.borderColor;
                // draw the line
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(1, 10);
                context.lineTo(50, 10);
                context.stroke();
                context.fillStyle = style.backgroundColor;
                context.setLineDash([]);
                context.lineWidth = 1;
                // draw a circle at the middle of the line
                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(25, 10, 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                context.fill();
                return canvas;
              })() as unknown as LegendItem,
              datasetIndex: meta.index,
            } as unknown as LegendItem;
          });
        },
      },
    },
  },
  scales: {
    x: {
      grid: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
  },
  layout: {
    padding: {
      top: 35,
    },
  },
};
```

Or see the full Codesandbox example here:
[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-chartjs-line-legend-with-small-circle-pointstyle-in-middle-cxnth8?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A42%2C58&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu0t2edl00063j6j1k6iig4h%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu0t2edk00023j6jc437ri08%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu0t2edk00033j6j10wcvhcq%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu0t2edk00053j6jpfqeq5sx%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clu0t2edk00023j6jc437ri08%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu0t2edk00023j6jc437ri08%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu0t6f5w00023j6j7a4qum34%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A42%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A58%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A42%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A58%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clu0t6f5w00023j6j7a4qum34%2522%257D%252C%2522clu0t2edk00053j6jpfqeq5sx%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu0t2edk00043j6jef3p5vhn%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu0t2edk00053j6jpfqeq5sx%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clu0t2edk00043j6jef3p5vhn%2522%257D%252C%2522clu0t2edk00033j6j10wcvhcq%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu0t2edk00033j6j10wcvhcq%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)